# Will serialized object contain the same json content when serialized again (the crossbrowser case)

Tags: javascript, json, serialization, cross-browser

I need to perform deep object comparisons between source and target object that are pretty specific to my usage and are complex too. But I can simplify things if it was possible to compare object's json representations. I mean if it was guaranteed that the order of properties is preserved after serialization. In other words by having two objects:

`{ a: "a", b: "b" }` and `{ b: "b", a: "a" }` which have the same content but whose json representations are different.

There are two cases that can be described by the following code snippets:

The first one:

```
var json = '{"a":"a","b":"b"}';
var x = JSON.parse(json);
var y = JSON.parse(json);
var comparison = JSON.stringify(x) === JSON.stringify(y); // will it always be true?
```

The second one:

```
var json = '{"a":"a","b":"b"}';
var x = JSON.parse(json);
var y = JSON.parse(json);

delete y.a;
delete y.b;

y.b = "b"; // Notice the order is changed
y.a = "a"; // Notice the order is changed

var comparison = JSON.stringify(x) === JSON.stringify(y); // will it always be true?
```

The questions:

- Will both cases be always true for all browsers?
- Are there any other scenarios that can make JSON.stringify(x) !== JSON.stringify(y)
- Is there a way to achieve previously described guarantee via implementing own serialization technique (like for example sorting properties before serializing)

That's it, thanks!

Comment: Comparing JSON is not reliable and not proper way to compare objects. `JSON.stringify({a: 1}) == JSON.stringify({a: 2, toJSON: function() { return {a: 1}}}); // true`

Comment: And the first use case will never ever be true.

Comment: Nice one, but maybe it's time (for me) to implement some sort of JsonS (stands for Json-Sorted)? Than it would be possible to achieve mentioned guarantees

Comment: As for the "And the first use case will never ever be true", my browser's console says the opposite

Comment: Of course go ahead, however I think it's simpler to implement recursive function to compare two objects.

Comment: Sorry I missread, yes in that case it's true. I mean that result of two JSON.parse cannot be strictly equal.

Comment: Order in objects is not guaranteed. You can take a look how compare is done in e.g.. http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual or in http://lodash.com/docs#isEqual

Comment: If you just want to compare two object use a function similar to this one: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.0-rc.3/src/Angular.js#L828 (it handles all the edge cases). Moreover instead of implementing your own data structure you can take a look at http://www.collectionsjs.com

Comment: @Miszy nice link: collectionsjs.com

Comment: https://github.com/lu4/jsons here I've modified the JSON 3 implementation of JSON to support JSON with sorted object properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I've forked and modified JSON 3 implementation to support JSON content with sorted object keys, hope it'll help somebody https://github.com/lu4/jsons